# volume of solid rotating about $x=1$ line

Tags: multivariable-calculus

> Find volume of solid obtained by rotating the regin $\mathbb{R}$ formed by $y=e^{x},x=0,y=0$ about the line  $x=1$ is

What i try :: [image]

Using Disk Method

Volume of solid obtained by rotating the regin $\mathbb{R}$ about $x=1$ line as

$$V=\pi\int^{1}_{0}1^2dy+\pi\int^{e}_{1}x^2dy$$

$$V=\pi+\pi\int^{e}_{1}\ln^2(y)dy$$

Can anyone please tell me is integral for volume is right, If not then please tell me How do i solve it, Thanks

Comment: The question mentions the line $x=1$, but your answer mentions the line $x=2$ instead. Why?

Comment: OK I see your edit. Now it is correct. Deleting my answer. You wrote $x = 2$ - that is a typo but your bounds in integration are correct.

Comment: I have edited it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you are probably well aware, the formula for this disk method that you want to employ is

$$V=\int_\Omega\pi R^2(y) dy.$$ You are correct to break it up into two regions and thus your integral $$\pi\int_0^1 dy$$ is correct. Your error is that $\ln(y)$ is not the radius of the second region but instead you should have that $R(y) = 1 - \ln(y)$ where $y\in (1,e)$ thus

$$V=\pi\int^{1}_{0}dy+\pi\int^{e}_{1}(1 - \ln(y))^2dy.$$

Let me know if you need any more explanation.